# How to use save dialog to save an XML file from the cell click event of DataGridView Cells?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datagrid view and in one of the cells I have to provide download file option. I am creating the XML file on the fly and when the user will click on the download button, he/she should be able to do so.

Here is my code:

```
private void DownloadFile(ScriptInfo scriptInfo)
        {
            XDocument doc =
                         new XDocument(
                           new XElement("scriptfilenames",
                               new XElement("SqlEye",
                                   new XElement("scriptfilename", new XAttribute("fileName", scriptInfo.FileName),
                                       new XElement("warnings",
                                        scriptInfo.ErrorMessages[RuleAction.Error].Select(x => new XElement("warning", new XAttribute("value", x)))),
                                        new XElement("remarks",
                                        scriptInfo.ErrorMessages[RuleAction.warning].Select(x => new XElement("remark", new XAttribute("value", x))))
                                        ))));

            string fileName = scriptInfo.FileName;
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
            string fileExtension = ".xml";

            byte[] byteData = null;

            //show save as dialog
            using (SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog())
            {
                //Set Save dialog properties
                saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Files (*" + fileExtension + ")|*" + fileExtension;
                saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save File as";
                saveFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;
                saveFileDialog1.FileName = fileName;

                if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    //what will be here????
                }
            }
           
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
                    doc.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName);                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, this should help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfezx97z.aspx
Check if filename is not empty, create filestream and write your data as in the example on msdn.

Answer (score 0):

Ok try this it will perfectly work. If its a server based-database then try this..

```
   string s = cncInfoDataGridView.Rows[dgvCell.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
   File.WriteAllBytes(saveFileDialog1.FileName, byteData);
   byteData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
```

If you are using a localdatabase then try below code.

```
    SqlCeConnection cnn = new SqlCeConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.CncConnectionString);
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileDialog.FileName);
                byte[] SqlTypeBlob = File.ReadAllBytes(fileDialog.FileName);
                cncInfoDataGridView.Rows[dgvCell.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = fileInfo.Name;
                SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO CncInfo (Drawings) VALUES (@DATA)", cnn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATA", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
                cmd.Parameters["@DATA"].Value = SqlTypeBlob;
                cnn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cnn.Close();
```

if anything else then this

```
  byteData = _myAttachments[dgvCell.ColumnIndex];
  File.WriteAllBytes(saveFileDialog1.FileName, byteData);
```

If this works please close this and give me a approve click for my answer.
Peace out!!!!!!!!